# CodeIgniter callback function not displayed

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback

I found other people with the same issue but couldn't find the solution to my problem. My error message is not displayed when the login fails if using the callback function.

loginController.php

```
public function validate_credentials () {

        $this->load->model('users_model');
        $query = $this->users_model->validate();

        if($query)
       {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('/member/homes'); 
       }
       else
       {
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|callback_check_username_exists'); //test
         $data['lofin_failed'] = 'Wrong usename or password'; // I added this line in the meantime to display an error message.

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('navbar');
            $this->load->view('loginForm', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');             
       }   
    }

    public function check_username_exists()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username_exists', 'Wrong username or password!!');
        return false;
    }
```

users_model.php

```
public function validate() {        
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('game_players');

        if($query -> num_rows() == 1) {       // if we have one match
            return true;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Your call back function should have an argument. Try declaring it as `check_user_exists(username)`

Comment: * `public function check_username_exists($username)`

Comment: I added `$username` to the function declarion but it didn't help. Is there a way to see the content of the message or why it is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

There is form validation rule :

> is_unique[table.field]

that checks database if the username is unique, you don't need callback.

You can check it here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

And you can use session flashdata instead of $data['lofin_failed'] 
you can check that here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Good to know about the is_unique, however here I need to check if the username matches the password in the database so that's not enough to check if the username is unique

Comment: So you want to use callback to show validation error if user is not in your database? If I am correct why don't you return num_rows from model and then check in controller and if it is 0, if it is, set flash data and redirect it to home page where you have div that checks for flashdata error or something like that. 
`$this->session->set_flashdata('error','Username or Password are incorrect.');redirect('/home', 'refresh');` and on home page you will have `<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error') != '') echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$this->session->flashdata('error')."</div>"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I simply forgot to add `echo validation_errors();` at the beginning of the page....